# cordova platform add ios not working on mac (An error occured during creation of ios sub-project)

Tags: ios, cordova-3

when I am adding paltform of ios I am having this error.

[Error: An error occured during creation of ios sub-project. /bin/sh: /Users/muhammadtalal/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.1.0/bin/create: No such file or directory
]

I have searched on internet and I found this link 
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cordova-issues/201307.mbox/%3CJIRA.12657795.1373912136728.51796.1373912569815@arcas%3E

i tried this to but its still not working

The version of cordova is 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error on my Mac. This is how I fixed it:

1. Went to http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/
2. Downloaded the latest cordova-3.1.0-src.zip.
3. Extracted the zip and inside extracted the zip named 'cordova-ios.zip'.
4. Copy the content of the second zip you extracted (Using terminal) to '/Users/username/.cordova/'

Comment: yes that correct but after it I am having problem in build project through cli
cordova build ios

Compiling app on platform "ios" via command "/Users/muhammadtalal/ipad/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/build" 
[Error: An error occurred while building the ios project.Unknown option: n

Comment: I am having the same issue. Error: "An error occurred while building the ios project.Unknown option: n". Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 5):

If you guys are having an error "Unknown option: n", you probably have installed XAMPP or something else which changed the PATH environment. edit your .profile and put the XAMPP binary path to the last of the PATH environment.

Comment: it is working by commenting XAMPP bin like so # export /PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin:$PATH

Comment: @justmyfreak  What consequences does comment that line of code? Can you answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617471/cordova-platform-add-ios-in-mac-osx-yosemite