# cordova platform add ios

Tags: ios, cordova

I tried to add ios platform to my phonegap project, but failed. I've already added the android platform successfully. The development environment is Mac. My Xcode version is above 5. I already installed node.js, ant, cordova, phonegap, and so on. This is my first time to ask a question. I already checked other similar questions, but it does not work. Anybody can give some suggestions?

When I run `cordova platform add ios` in my project file, here is the console output:

```
Creating ios project...

Unknown option: n

Usage: head [-options] <url>...
    -m <method>   use method for the request (default is 'HEAD')

Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater.

Error: /Users/Magnusmode/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 2
   at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
   at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)"
```

Maybe I added the wrong path of Xcode to ~/.profile. Here is the part of the ~/.profile:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs:"$PATH"
export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk:"$PATH"
export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app:"$PATH"
export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications:"$PATH"
```

Comment: are you running the new xcode preview? or the stable version?

Comment: I follow bentsai's suggestion to comment the # export /PATH=?Applications/XAMPP.....  Then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161203/139) and [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708592/phonegap-issue-on-adding-platform), it sounds like you're on the right track with looking at your `PATH` variable.

In particular, if you have XAMPP installed, try commenting out this line from your `~/.profile` like so:

`# export /PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I added ios successfully.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @bentsai What consequences does comment that line of code? Can you answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617471/cordova-platform-add-ios-in-mac-osx-yosemite